# Disemvowelled Books

Tags: literature

I recently put together a list of books by some well-known authors, but something went horribly wrong when I tried to print it out. The first entry in the list was completely unreadable, but the rest were all just missing their vowels.
Not only that, but the two halves of the list were all muddled up. Originally there was a clear relationship between the title in the first column and the title in the second.

**Question** Can you work out what the original titles were, what the matches were, and what the first entry in the list should have read?

```
1 ??????????????????????? A LVSFTHTWNS
2   CRR                   B THCLMNGFSLPNGBTY
3   NTRVWWTHTHVMPR        C THCCKSCLLNG
4   PBBLNTHSKY            D SPRTSNBNDG
5   STRQST                E RG
6   THMYSTRSFFRTSTYLS     F LGCYFTRRR
7   THNDRMDSTRN           G GNTSBRD
8   THPLGRMSRGRSS         H DVDSTRRSPCRNGR
9   THWSPFCTRY            I DDSN
10  WTHSHDDRNGFLL         J CNSDRPHLBS
```

*Thanks to Deusovi for the title*

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed you didn't call this "Disemvowelled Books".

Comment: I think you may want to double check A, I think you left out a word of that title.

Comment: @Irishpanda - well spotted, though it's actually a case of words in the wrong order.

Comment: Another excellent puzzle!

Comment: Well, well done!

Comment: Nice puzzle, though I think all of your `Y`s should be considered vowels.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Column 1:

> 1 Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone
>  2 Carrie
>  3 Interview With the Vampire
>  4 Pebble in the Sky
>  5 Star Quest
>  6 The Mysterious Affair at Styles
>  7 The Andromeda Strain
>  8 The Pilgrim's Regress
>  9 The Wasp Factory
>  10 With Shuddering Fall

Column 2:

> A Lives of the Twins
>  B The Claiming of Sleeping Beauty
>  C Cuckoos Calling
>  D Spirits in Bondage
>  E Rage
>  F Legacy of Terror
>  G Giants Bread
>  H David Starr Space Ranger
>  I Odds On
>  J Consider Phlebas

Matches:

> The pattern is that the first column holds an author's first book under their own name, the second holds their first title written under a pseudonym.
>  1-C (J K Rowling/Robert Galbraith)
>  2-E (Stephen King/Richard Bachman)
>  3-B (Anne Rice/A N Roquelaure)
>  4-H (Isaac Asimov/Paul French)
>  5-F (Dean Koontz/Deanna Dwyer)
>  6-G (Agatha Christie/Mary Westmacott)
>  7-I  (Michael Crichton/John Lange)
>  8-D (C S Lewis/Clive Hamilton)
>  9-J (Iain Banks/Iain M Banks)
>  10-A (Joyce Carol Oates/Rosamond Smith)

Comment: Why is formatting so hard >_<

Comment: Why HP1 as opposed to any of the other Rowling books?

Comment: I'll put that in my answer as soon as I sort out the formatting :\

Comment: There is something a bit more specific about the second column.

Comment: Added in, took me a minute to spot it

Comment: It looks like you beat Fillet by a whisker in getting all the titles correct too. (Just to be pedantic, though, F wasn't K R Dwyer).

Comment: Corrected. I was fooled by the Amazon entry for it in Google. That'll teach me to be lazy and not click the link!

Comment: 12 seconds! But good job, especially for getting all the aliases and the full explanation of the left and right columns.

Comment: I had it a fair bit earlier, but spent forever making the spoiler tag work right. They are the bane of my existence :{

Comment: Weird, why the downvote?

Answer (score 4):

1 ???????????????????????

2   CRR

> Carrie (Stephen King)

3   NTRVWWTHTHVMPR

> Interview with a vampire (Anne Rice)

4   PBBLNTHSKY

> Pebble in the sky (Isaac Asimov)

5   STRQST

> Star Quest (Dean R. Koontz)

6   THMYSTRSFFRTSTYLS

> The mysterious affair at Styles (Agatha Christie)

7   THNDRMDSTRN

> The Andromeda Strain (Michael Crichton)

8   THPLGRMSRGRSS

> The Pilgrim's Regress (CS Lewis)

9   THWSPFCTRY

> The wasp Factory (Iain Banks)

10  WTHSHDDRNGFLL

> With Shuddering Fall (Joyce Oates)

A THLVSFTWNS

> Lives of the Twins (Joyce Oates)

B THCLMNGFSLPNGBTY

> B The Claiming of Sleeping Beauty (Anne Rice)

C THCCKSCLLNG

> C The Cuckoo's Calling (Robert Galbraith, aka JK Rowling)

D SPRTSNBNDG

> Spirits in Bondage (CS Lewis)

E RG

> Rage (Stephen King)

F LGCYFTRRR

> Legacy of Terror (Dean Koontz)

G GNTSBRD

> Giant's Bread (Agatha Christie)

H DVDSTRRSPCRNGR

> David Starr Space Ranger (Isaac Asimov)

I DDSN

> Odds On (Michael Crichton)

J CNSDRPHLBS

> Consider Phlebas  (Iain Banks)

Matching everything up, with each author having an entry on the left and right columns leaves...

> Robert Galbraith/JKR Unmatched. But the left side has the debut novel of the author (disregarding pseudonyms), so the answer is "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone".

Comment: What's significant about the titles in the second column?

Answer (score 2):

An exceptionally incomplete answer:

1st column

> **6** The Mysterious Affair at Styles
> **7** The Andromeda Strain
> **8** The Pilgrim's Regress
> **10** With Shuddering Fall

2nd column

> **B** The Claiming of Sleeping Beauty (Which I should not have googled at work)
>  **C** The Cuckoo's Calling

Comment: I've hit a wall, so I'll throw in with you: 3: Interview with a Vampire; 4: Pebble in the sky; 5: Star Quest; 9: The Wasp Factory; A: Lives of the Twins; E: Rogue; F: Legacy of Terror; G: Giant's Bread; J: Consider Phlebas

Comment: @Josh I (partially) guessed the link between the two columns, worked out what the first few letters of 'Interview' would be, and then somehow didn't see it. I'm a fool.